# Filter documents with mongo-connector to elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have severals documents as :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ff164421a6ff18b2a3e8af"),
"type" : "FAC", 
    "nda" : "a", 
    "c" : 15.0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ff173121a6ff18b2a3e8b2"), 
    "type" : "CMDE", 
    "nda" : "r", 
    "c" : 15.0
}
```

Is it possible to be able to transfer just one type of document to elasticsearch ?

Comment: Answer would be yes! But what have you tried?

Comment: For now I don't see how it is possible with mongo-connector to choose a type of document to transfer. I just saw that we could choose the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are querying documents from MongoDB

try this query

```
db.collection.find( { "type" : "FAC" } )
```

This will give you all documents of type "FAC".
In case you need all documents of type "CMDE" try this

```
db.collection.find( { "type" : "CMDE" } )
```

In case you are querying the mongo db documents using mongodb connector then you need the following ES query

```
GET _search
{
  "query": { 
    "filtered": { 
      "filter": { "term":  {  "type" : "FAC" }}
                 },
   "match_all": {} 
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works from mongodb. But I was wondering if in mongo-connector there was not the possibility of doing a query

Comment: It is exactly query that I will wish to do but to mongo-connector. Because I want a document type on elasticsearch